# Four integrals, how can I expedite the calculations?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have to calculate the following multiple integrals (4 integrals)

```
ClearAll[gg, T, H, F, G, p, q , a, x]
gg = Assuming[T > 0 && H > 0 && G > 0 && F > 0 && p > 0 && q > 0, 
  Integrate[Integrate[Integrate[Integrate[1/(F G H T)  Exp[-y/T] Exp[-a/F] 
    Exp[-b/H] Exp[-x/G], {y,0, (p (1 + F a) + b q ((1 + F a)/(1 + G x)))}], 
    {a, 0, ∞}], {x, 0, ∞}], {b, 0, ∞}]]
```

The calculation takes too much time.
Is there a way to expedite the process?

Thanks.

[EDIT] Faster:

```
gg = Assuming[T > 0 && H > 0 && G > 0 && F > 0 && p > 0 && q > 0, 
  Integrate[1/(F G H T) Exp[-y/T] Exp[-a/F] Exp[-b/H] Exp[-x/G], {y, 
0, (p (1 + F a) + b q ((1 + F a)/(1 + G x)))}, {a, 0, \[Infinity]}, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, {b, 0, \[Infinity]}]]
```

I got the following result that I'm not sure it's correct:

[image]

Comment: I have tried but I'm not sure that the result is correct. I mean in the result compare $b$, $a$ and $x$ variables. How can do that? The variable $y$ should be integrated between $0$ and 
    $(p (1 + F a) + b q ((1 + F a)/(1 + G x)))$ where the second term contains other variables.

Comment: Well, it _is_ successively integrated given those (partially symbolic) ranges. What is it you do not like in the result *Mathematica* hands you?

Comment: Integrating over $a$, $x$ and $b$, I don't understand how I can find these in the result.

Comment: Your `[Edit]` is wrong... and it was me who suggested it.Blush!

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand where is the error in [EDIT]

Answer (score 2):

Perform the three "easy" integrals first:

```
gg = Assuming[T > 0 && H > 0 && G > 0 && F > 0 && p > 0 && q > 0, 
  1/(F G H T) Integrate[ 
    Exp[-y/T] Exp[-a/F] Exp[-b/H] Exp[-x/G], 
     {a, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
     {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
     {b, 0, \[Infinity]}]
             ]
```

(*
$\frac{e^{-\frac{y}{T}}}{T}$
*)

and the "hard" one last:

```
Integrate[gg, {y, 0, (p (1 + F a) + b q ((1 + F a)/(1 + G x)))}]
```

(* 
$1-\exp \left(-\frac{(a F+1) (b q+G p x+p)}{G T x+T}\right)$
*)

Takes less than 0.4 second.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still not understand, because we can change the order. The integral over $y$ has parametric limit, i.e. in the limit there are the other variables. Instead doing the integral in the order proposed $a$, $x$ and $b$ are considered constants.

Comment: Hello, could someone explain the answer here above? As I said in my previous comment I don't understand why we still have variables in the result.